# How to fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 4

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make an 2d array and am using this code

```
public void createPwm()
{
   double[ ][ ] aryNumbers = new double[4][8];
   aryNumbers[0][0] = new Double((3 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[0][1] = new Double((2 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[0][2] = new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[0][3] = new Double((4 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[1][0] = new Double((4 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[1][1] = new Double((3 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[1][2] =  new Double((2 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[1][3] =  new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 0.1));
   aryNumbers[2][0] = new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[2][1] = new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[2][2] = new Double((6 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[2][3] =  new Double((2 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[3][0] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[3][1] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[3][2] = new Double((10 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[3][3] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[4][0] =  new Double(.1 / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[4][1] = new Double((10 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[4][2] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[4][3] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[5][0] = new Double((6 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[5][1] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[5][2] = new Double((4 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[5][3] =  new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[6][0] = new Double((8 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[6][1] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[6][2] = new Double((2 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[6][3] =  new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[7][0] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[7][1] = new Double((0 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[7][2] = new Double((9 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[7][3] = new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[8][0] =  new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[8][1] = new Double((6 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[8][2] = new Double((2 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));
   aryNumbers[8][3] = new Double((1 + .1) / (10 + 4 * 10));             
}
```

but I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 4 around array[4][0].

Answer (score 0):

Look at your array declaration:

```
new double[4][8]
```

The first dimension of the array has only 4 elements.  So you get an error when you try to access the 5th element:

```
aryNumbers[4][0]
```

In fact, your code is *trying* to access all the way up through a *9th* element:

```
aryNumbers[8][0]
```

From the looks of it, you probably *meant* to declare the array like this:

```
new double[9][4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the index `4` when there are four entries on that "position" (`new double[4][8]`). The left-most index can be `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` in that case.